# Colons preceding informats in SAS INPUT statement

Tags: date, input, sas

I am wondering why, if SAS is reading, through an INPUT statement in a data step, only date variable(s), it seems necessary to write a colon before each informat name, while, if the variables' list begins with another type of variable (eg a character variable), colons are not needed in front of informats.
   To illustrate my question, two small programs (see below). The first one generates invalid data for date (as long as I do not write a colon before mmddyy10., to get  **INPUT date :mmddyy10.;**), while the second does not.
   Strange, is not it? There is probably some explanation to this, but despite searching through SAS support documentation and forums I am unable to discover what it could be. Any help welcome!
    Anyway, if I had sooner understood what is at stake I had saved a couple of hours spent at trying to solve this question.

```
* program #1;
DATA _NULL_;
    INPUT date mmddyy10.;
    DATALINES;
    09/14/2012
    09/15/2012 
    ;
  RUN;
  PROC PRINT; RUN;

* program #2;
  DATA _NULL_;
     INPUT id $ date mmddyy10.;
   DATALINES;
    A 09/14/2012
    B 09/15/2012 
   ;
  RUN;
```

Comment: Did you mean **colon** instead of column?   Like `:`

Comment: Yes, colon, not column. Sorry!

Comment: If slight formal modifications of answers' titles are not impossible or forbidden, I would suggest (to people authorized to edit things on Stackoverflow) to substitute "Colons" to "Columns" at least in the above Subject line, in order to make subsequent search by users more efficient.    Modifying the three incorrect occurrences of "column" instead of "colon" in the answer's text is less important, I think, and would make Tom's comment strange. Thanks in advance for this editing and apologizes for my typos.

Comment: Thanks for having taken into account the suggestions I made above about editing my question.

Answer (score 1):

In your first program you told SAS to read the first 10 characters as a date.  But the first 4 characters are all spaces.  So you asked it to try to convert `'    09/14/'` into a date.  I recommend always typing the DATALINES (aka CARDS) statement starting in column one to prevent the auto-indent feature of your editor from causing your lines of data to be indented also.

The colon (`:`) in front of the inline informat specification tells SAS to use list mode input instead of formatted input. With formatted input SAS reads the number of characters the format specifies. With list mode SAS reads the next field in the line, based on the current delimiter and dsd setting.  The width used for the informat is adjusted to match the actual width of the next field in the line.

Example:

```
data test;
  length name1-name3 $30 ;
  input @1 name1
        @1 name2 $5.
        @1 name3 :$5. 
  ;
cards;
Elizabeth
;
```

Results:

```
Obs      name1      name2      name3

 1     Elizabeth    Eliza    Elizabeth
```

Comment: Should I interpret the INPUT statement in your example as the possibility to modify the kind of input within an INPUT statement (moving, here, from formatted input to list input)?

Comment: Yes.  NAME1 is input using normal list mode without an added inline informat, NAME2 is input using formatted mode and NAME3 is list mode but with an inline informat.  The @ is just so they all start reading at the same place so we can compare the effect on reading the same input stream.

Comment: Thanks!   Up to now I did not realize that  `name3 :$5.` belongs to list mode while the same code but without the colon makes use of the formatted mode.     Could you explain the role of the LENGTH statement in this precise context?    In fact, if I omit this statement, I get an invalid data message for name1.    And, if I limit the LENGTH statement to name1, the results are similar to your results, except that name3's value is then truncated to the five first characters of Elizabeth (ie Eliza).

Comment: The length statement will define the type and storage length for your variables. If you don't define the variables before you reference them then SAS must make a guess at how to define them based on how you first use them.  If it has nothing to guide it the variable will be made numeric, which is why NAME1 is missing.  If the first place it sees the variable it is associated with a format or informat it will match the type and guess the length based on the format/informat width.